# Diagonalization of Bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, diagonalization, bilinear-form

I got this bilinear form: $f:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=-x_1y_1-16x_2y_2+4x_1y_2+4x_2y_1$$
I am asked to find the basis that diagonalizes the matrix.

Using the standard method (eigenvalues/eigenvectors), I found that $P=\begin{pmatrix}4 & 1\\1 & -4\end{pmatrix}$ diagonalizes $f$ into $diag\{0,-17\}$.

However, this is a fairly tedious process (if you want to verify the result) and I am sure there is a much simpler one (both intuitively and the fact that this is supposed to be a <15-minute problem). So I expressed the bilinear form as a quadratic form:

$$q(x,y)=-x^2-16y^2+8xy$$
$$[q]_E = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 4\\4 & -16\end{pmatrix}$$

I noticed that $-x^2-16y^2+8xy=-(x-4y)^2$, so it should be very easy to get the basis using Lagrange's method. I get that:

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

And:
$$x'=x-4y$$
$$y'=?$$

Here I am stuck. $y'$ can't be $0$ because it would make the diagonalizing matrix singular. I tried with an arbitrary number, but it didn't work out. Also tried the congruence by elementary steps method (not sure what the official name is—it's the algorithm where you perform elementary row/column operations on the matrix until you reach the diagonal, and then do just the row operations on $I$), and the result was similar. What am I missing?

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791422/diagonalizing-a-bilinear-form/792071#792071

Comment: Yes, this is the algorithm I meant under "congruence by elementary steps method", I just don't know if it has a name. It didn't work out and gave essentially the same result as the Lagrange method.

Comment: Are you sure you’ve gotten the matrices right? The matrix for the original bilinear form is *not* symmetric, but when I work backwards from your $P$ and eigenvalues I end up with a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I wrote the bilinear form incorrectly here, now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get if I apply the "congruence by elementary steps method" (also don't know what it is called ;)).
First step:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & :: & 1 & 0\\
4 & 0 & :: & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
Second step:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & :: & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & :: & 4 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
The matrix on the right is a change of basis matrix, right? Remember congruence and similarity is not the same. Congruent matrices have same numbers of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues, whereas similarity ensures the same eigenvalues.

Comment: OK I think my problem was that I thought that the basis was {(1,4),(0,1)}, while in fact it is {(1,0),(4,1)}. So the matrix on the right is in your answer is actually $P^t$, where $P^tAP=D$. The change of basis matrix would be the transpose of the matrix on the right.